# GreenDAO not respecting @Unique fields

Tags: android

First time implementing `GreenDAO`. Been reading a lot of the other questions and I feel I've followed all of them.

My simple Entity:

```
@Entity(
        indexes = {
                @Index(value = "searchTerm", unique = true)
        }
)
public class SearchTerm
{
    @Id private Long id;
    //    @Unique have also tried this
    //    @Index(unique = true) have also tried this
    private String searchTerm;
    private Date date;
}
```

I then insert into the table using `searchTermDao.insertOrReplace(searchTerm)`. The problem is it will store multiple entries where the `searchTerm` is exactly the same. What am I doing wrong?

```
private SearchViewQueryTextEvent storeSearchTerm(SearchViewQueryTextEvent queryTextEvent)
    {
        SearchTerm searchTerm = new SearchTerm();
        searchTerm.setSearchTerm(queryTextEvent.queryText().toString());
        searchTerm.setDate(new Date());
        searchTermDao.insertOrReplace(searchTerm);
        Log.d(TAG, "Stored new search term: " + searchTerm.getSearchTerm());
        return queryTextEvent;
    }
```

**SOLUTION:**

Thanks to **Luiz** in comments I just upgraded the database on initialisation:

```
DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper helper = new DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper(mContext, "search-db");
helper.onUpgrade(helper.getWritableDatabase(), 1, 2);
Database db = helper.getWritableDb();
return new DaoMaster(db).newSession();
```

`.onUpgrade()` only needed to be called once.

Comment: Are you using SQLite or ORMLite or something else?

Comment: I've kept everything default so I would assume SQLite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same problem and after reviewing the logs I realized that the database was not being updated after I applied the annotation `@Unique`.

To fix this issue, try to increase the database version inside your class that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper` and drop your table inside your `onUpgrade()` method.

```
  private static final int VERSION = 2; //+ one number

     @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + table_name);
            onCreate(db);
        }
```